# handling URL variables in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 app with a route defined  `{controller}/{action}/{Username}`.
I'd like to be  able  to hide the username  when I do a GET request  via action-link. 
Point to note here is that I use the  username variable  in the view that is rendered to fill out the  username field.

I don't want a situation where others can hack around with usernames to get at records they are  not supposed to see.

Is there a way to use an action filter to facilitate  the above? i.e use a slug or something in the url after the username variable has been applied.

Answer (score -1):

you can add a route path as

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                "RouteName",                                              // Route name
                "ActionName/",                          
                new { controller = "controllerName", action = "ActionName", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```

I think it might be helpful.